# Distant Supervision Code

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I have to implement Distant Supervision python code. I have constructed a feature vector for the unlabeled pool of data. The feature vector contains the lexical features of the sentences. I am not able to understand how to apply the classifier on this vector.

**EDIT:**
1) I have an unlabeled pool of data from which I want to extract new relations.
2) I have a file which contains typeOf relations. So on the basis of the relations in this file I want to get new relations in my data.
3) I have extracted the lexical features from the sentences in the following format:

[[sequence of words between the entities","POS tags of these words","Flag indicating which entity came first","Window of k words to the left of entity 1","POS tags of these words","Window of k words to the right of entity 2","POS of these tags"],....]

This is an example of the data existing in the typeOf.txt file(relation file):

Tupi ----------------- 2D animation software
Pencil2D -----------2D animation software
SWFTools ---- -----2D animation software
Synfig -------------- 2D animation software
Flipnote Studio --- 2D animation software

I hope this makes my query a little bit more clearer.

Comment: Please, insert your code here to try to get some help. Your question, so far, is too broad. People don't have enough information to guess what you want. Check [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

There are few information to answer this question, but I'll try.

Distant Supervision is an alternative approach to generating training data, however, (if I understand you) you already have the training data which is the lexical features of the sentences that you described. So, based on the principle that you already have the training set, now, you need to "classify". If I understand you, you do not have the labels, so you should use some unsupervised learning technique. There are many algorithms for unsupervised learning, the most popular is k-means. For example, in the snippet code below, the variable X contains the vectors to be clustered, where you can just substitute by your vectors of lexical features.

Hope I helped you.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
              [4, 2], [4, 4], [4, 0]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
kmeans.labels_

kmeans.predict([[0, 0], [4, 4]])

kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

Comment: I have edited my post to add more information. I guess the labels you are referring to are the ones listed in the typeOf.txt file.